# How much time a flutter app stay installed on a physical device after it is loaded with the flutter run -- release command?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Hello yesterday I installed a flutter app on an Android smartphone with the command 'flutter run --release' , but i want know how much time the app remains installed on the smartphone.
Thank you very much to everyone that answer me!

I think  one week at least, but i don't sure..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any time limit for this, since I made multiple apps and installed it on physical device through this command and I was always able to find it whenever I needed.